# laravel: problem in delete Route function

Tags: php, laravel, routes, crud, laravel-5.5

I'm working on Laravel5.5, and i'm doing the Crud operation. currently i'm working on deleting, but i got **Route** problem issue.

this is the Routes for crud operations of controll

```
    // Test Management
Route::group([ 'prefix' => 'tests'], function () {
    Route::get('data', 'TestController@data')->name('tests.data');
    Route::get('{tests}/delete', 'TestController@destroy')->name('tests.delete');
    Route::get('{tests}/confirm-delete', 'TestController@getModelDelete')->name('tests.confirm-delete');

});
Route::resource('tests', 'TestController');
```

and this is where the links to the delete function comes where the user confirms the delete butttom

```
public function getModelDelete(Test $test)
{
    $model = 'tes'; # this model is for the path of the modal
    $confirm_route = $error = null;
    try {
        $confirm_route = route('admin.tests.delete', ['id' => $test->id]);
        return view('admin.layouts.modal_confirmation', compact('error', 'model', 'confirm_route'));
    } catch (GroupNotFoundException $e) {

        $error = trans('tes/message.error.destroy', compact('id'));
        return view('admin.layouts.modal_confirmation', compact('error', 'model', 'confirm_route'));
    }
}
```

this is the modal for confiming delete

```
<div class="modal-header">
   <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria- 
       hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" 
        id="user_delete_confirm_title">@lang($model.'/modal.title')</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    @if($error)
       <div>{!! $error !!}</div>
    @else
       @lang($model.'/modal.body')
    @endif
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data- 
          dismiss="modal">@lang($model.'/modal.cancel')</button>
     @if(!$error)
        <a href="{{ $confirm_route }}" type="button" class="btn btn- 
              danger">@lang($model.'/modal.confirm')</a>
     @endif
</div>
```

and this is the delete method in controller

```
 public function destroy($id)
{
    $test = Test::find($id);
    $test->delete();
    return redirect('admin/tests')->with('success', trans('tes/message.success.delete'));

    }
}
```

The thing is when i hit confirm delete buttom it says Page not found and this is url it will go

> http://localhost/bsproject/public/index.php/admin/tests//delete

and i noticed that there's extra backslash. and thank you!

Comment: You can use `postman` application to check urls like delete, post, etc. In browser in url if you hit then it's always `get`.

Answer (score 1):

When using the `route()` helper, passing a variable must have a **key** of the url **parameter**.

For your case, instead of `id` you should use `tests`:

```
$confirm_route = route('admin.tests.delete', ['tests' => $test->id]);
```

I would advise changing the route to `id` so it makes more sense:

```
Route::get('{id}/delete', 'TestController@destroy')->name('tests.delete');
```

**Site note**: It would be best to use `Route::delete()` to be clear with your routes. `::get()` assumes you are getting a page or data. This will require changing your modal to use a `<form>` which wraps your `<button>`.

Comment: this is not working it, the same problem with the extra forward slash in url

Comment: @abokorhassan Also notice you have `index.php` in your url. This will probably need to be taken out (Check your `.env` file to see if set there).